# Smart Ammo vs. People: What's the TL of a person?

Tags: weapons, mongoose-traveller-2

Smart weapons "*gain a DM to their attack rolls equal to the difference between their TL and that of the target*," (CRB75).

When using a smart weapon against a vehicle that makes perfect sense. But what about when using a smart weapon against a person? The *Central Supply Catalogue* gives us the option of smart ammo for pistols and rifles at TL 10 (guided ammo, page140).

Do characters have a TL? Do we use the TL of their armour? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any answer in the books so you may have to "House Rule" this.

The simplest solution would be to apply a flat +1 DM to the attack roll, perhaps increasing to +2 at TL 13, say. Arbitrary modifiers are a common method of creating *ad hoc* fixes to situations not covered in the rules.

Another solution may be to apply a DM equal to the difference between their TL and the target's Dex characteristic. By defining the target character's TL as their Dex, you maintain the wording of the text. I think this solution is less arbitrary and more in keeping with the "flavor" of the rule.

Answer (score 1):

You use the tech level of the armor they are wearing, so combat armor of tech 12, or in the case of say flax armor rated at I think 8 as base, you use the level it was made at. So if the planet cop is using local-made armor you use the planet's tech level. So you use the item's base tech or the planet's, whichever is best.